# Save Data with KnocloutJS viewmodel to server

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I want to save my ViewModel to my SQL server. The standard knockout ko.toJSON(viewModel) keeps giving me an undefined error, so after some digging i found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690292/knockout-post-json-form-data-posts-null), but still keeps giving me undefined.

Here is the code for my viewmodel, this is just a currency conversion table that gets the Conversion Rate between 2 currencies.

```
   //ko Event Handler for datepicker.js
    ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
            $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable(ev.date);
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).datepicker("setValue", value);
        }
    };


    //Currency Model Definition
    var currency = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.DateCreated = ko.observable(formatJsonDate(data.DateCreated));
        self.CurrencyFrom = ko.observable(data.CurrencyFrom);
        self.CurrencyTo = ko.observable(data.CurrencyTo);
        self.ConversionRate = ko.observable(data.ConversionRate);

        //Yhoo Finance API
        ko.computed(function () {
            var from = self.CurrencyFrom(),
                 to = self.CurrencyTo();


            if (!from || !to) {
                self.ConversionRate("N/A");
                return;
            }

            getRate(from, to).done(function (YahooData) {
                console.log("got yahoo data for [" + from + "," + to + "]: ", YahooData);
                self.ConversionRate(YahooData.query.results.row.rate);
            });
        });
    }

    var NewDate = new Date().getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + new Date().getDate();


    var CurrencyModel = function (Currencies) {
        var self = this;
        self.Currencies = ko.observableArray(Currencies);

        self.AddCurrency = function () {
            self.Currencies.push({
                DateCreated: NewDate,
                CurrencyFrom: "",
                CurrencyTo: "",
                ConversionRate: ""
            });
        };

        self.RemoveCurrency = function (Currency) {
            self.Currencies.remove(Currency);
        };

        self.Save = function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "#",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: ko.mapping.toJSON(CurrencyModel),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    //I get undefined....
                    alert(ko.mapping.toJSON(CurrencyModel));
                },
                error: function (data) { alert("error" + data); }
            });
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "CurrencyConfiguration.aspx/GetConfiguredCurrencies",
            data: '{}',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (Result) {
                //                    callback(Result);
                var MappedCurrencies =
              $.map(Result.d,
             function (item) {
                 getRate(item.CurrencyFrom, item.CurrencyTo);
                 return new currency(item);
             }
       );
                self.Currencies(MappedCurrencies);

            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

    };

    function formatJsonDate(jsonDate) {
        var FormatDate = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        var Output = FormatDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (FormatDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + FormatDate.getDate();
        return (Output);
    };

    function getRate(from, to) {
        return $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D" + from + to + "%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=?");
    }

        function callback(data) {
        if (viewModel) {
            // model was initialized, update it
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
        } else {
            // or initialize and bind
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    }

    $('#Date').datepicker();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var VM = new CurrencyModel();
        ko.applyBindings(VM);
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data: ko.mapping.toJSON(CurrencyModel)
```

You are trying to JSONify the definition not the actual instance

Comment: If i Look at the $root element of CurrencyModel it shows: { "Currencies": [ { "DateCreated": "2013-01-20", "CurrencyFrom": "ZAR", "CurrencyTo": "USD", "ConversionRate": "0.1125" } ] }. So should I be mapping Currencies instead of CurrencyModel?

Comment: You need to use self or this, also you cant post and get like that, the operation are async so you will call the get before the post is done

Comment: What would be the better method of posting?, I data-bind my save to click event on a button

Comment: Either make the post return the data that you want to get from the get, or move the get into the success function of the post

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the [method](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) that you want to use:

```
ko.toJSON
```

rather than off the mapping object?

Comment: I get parsererror in my alert, for my debugging I do use ko.toJSON($root,null,2) and the JSON populates correctly

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In the code in your question, you've used ko.mapping.toJSON, and you should be using ko.toJSON.

Comment: ko.mapping.toJSON is much more powerfull than ko.toJSON. It works with circular references etc

Comment: In that case, then the issue is the one Anders has raised, you need to do ko.mapping.toJSON(self).